# Cannot save images in my folder after uploading them from react native app

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, backend

Hello everyone I'm trying to create an app with a backend where the user will be able to upload a profile pic. I'm using nodejs for the back with the framework Expressjs.
However, when I try to upload an image to my server from my react-native app nothing gets saved into my images folder.
I'm on iOS right now, I don't know if it changes anything.

When I tried to do the same but without react-native directly sending POST request using Postman I was able to do so.
I don't really know why I thought it would be extension name or something but it does not change anything.

Here is my backend code first : 
I'm using Multer for the upload

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : function(req, file, cb ){
        cb(null,'./images/');
    },
    filename : function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
    }
})
const upload = multer({ storage : storage,
    //filer only valide file == image
fileFilter: function(req,file,cb){
    let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if(ext != '.png' && ext != '.jpg' && ext !='jpeg'){
        return cb('Only images are allowed ')
    }
    cb(null, true)
},
    limits:{fieldSize: 25*1024*1024}
})
// route for photo TEST
router.post('/upload',upload.single('photo'), (req,res)=> {
    console.log('file',req.files);
    //console.log('body', req.body);
    res.status(200).json({
        message:'success!',
    });
});
```

And now this is what I do on my react-native app

```
const createFormData = (photo, body) =>{
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('photo', {
        name:photo.fileName,
        type:photo.type,
        uri : 
        Platform.OS === 'android' ? photo.uri : photo.uri.replace('file://', ''), // to be sure it works with android
    });
    Object.keys(body).forEach(key => {
        data.append(key, body[key]);
    });
    return data;

handleUploadPhoto = () =>{
        fetch('http://localhost:5050/api/new/upload',{
            method: 'POST',
            body: createFormData(this.state.dataPhoto,{userId : 'test'}),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log('upload succes', response);
            alert('Photo updated succesfully!')
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('upload failed', error);
            alert('Upload is not possible right now!');
        })
    };
```

I do get the alert("Photo updated succesfully on my screen" so I guess it works on the front but not on the back...
I load the image using react-native-image-picker

I don't get any error message but no files are saved into my images folder. 
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: @EI Pandario Maybe help you https://medium.com/@bmshamsnahid/nodejs-file-upload-using-multer-3a904516f6d2

Comment: Hey, so I read that but actually my problem comes from react native because it works perfectly using postman.

Comment: While uploading please check your image extension sync (caps or small)  .jped or .JPEG. I got the same problem in my previous project postman working fine but GUI not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not seeing anythign related to  console.log('file', req.files) which you printed ?

Verify when you upload , you are getting the file + the uploaded file related ojbects in the node console.

Enable the console body log and also view it console.log('body', req.body)

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, I forgot to add that the console.log(req.files) return me undefined and the consol.log(body) returns a huge "thing"which seems encrypted that I can't read.

Comment: Compare with postman req.files and with the ios / android app submission. So it means the uploaded file data is not sent to the node server.

Comment: When I use postman, I get undefined for the req.files and for the req.body [Object : null prototype ] {} I don't really know what it means. However it succesfully saved my file in my folder images.

Comment: So before I was trying to upload an image from the library and when I was trying to upload I got a very long encrypted message. However when I try to upload a image from my computer (with the front end) I get the same message as using postman but it does not save it. body [Object: null prototype] { photo: '', userId: '123' }

Comment: run this command and see what is the output you are getting console.log(json.stringify(req.files)); Compare with the Post man what is the input we are getting and similarly with your mobile data submission as well to drill down the issue further .

Comment: Hello, I managed to get it working now. Thanks for your help anyway it is because I was not giving a name for the file I believe.